# Auto-update a table where date equals today

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Project ( asp.net MVC - sql database)

I have the following SQL table:

**( tasks)**

- Task_ID
- Task_Name
- Start_Date
- End_Date
- Task_Statues.

Task_Statues has 1 of the 3 value **On progress**, **Finished** and **failed**. I need to auto-update it `Task` to **failed** if `today > End_Date` And `task statues == New`. I tried to put code in the Home Index view to update the table but I cannot find how to make it :(

My code is:

```
private  void UPP() {
    foreach (var item in db.TaskOrders.Where(a => a.EndDate > DateTime.Now)) {
        item.TaskState = "Failed";
        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to do that, e.g. using a library like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) to schedule the update as background job.
You also could call the method in a controller, or a custom [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2), but than you would need to ensure that the method is called regularly but not too often to avoid negative performance implications.